# LibreOffice set text fixed on frontpage

Tags: libreoffice

I would like to know if it's possible to set a text block on a fixed position on the front page using LibreOffice.

Comment: Is this question related to [the TextBlock class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(v=vs.110).aspx) as the tag suggests?  From the title it does not sound like you are asking about .NET programming.

Comment: No it ain't related to your mentioned subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Insert -> Frame -> Frame...` and specify the anchor `To page`.  Also you may want to go to the `Borders` tab and remove the borders.

After inserting the frame, move it by clicking and dragging.  Click inside to enter text in the frame.